# How can I map of buttons disappear after I click one JS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, button

I have a table with a list of items which has a button on each row, and I want each button to only be clicked once and then disappear after they click it once, but the other buttons stay till they are clicked.

I have the button linked to an action already and I have tried putting an id with the button and doing document.getElementById('creditBtn').style.display='none however it does not hide the button.

```
function submitCredit(reviewerId, reviewId) {
    let socialCredit = document.getElementById('socialCredit').value;
    const body1 = { credit: socialCredit };
    axios.put('http://localhost:8080/awardCredit/:' + reviewerId, body1)
        .then(alert("Submitted Credit"));
    const body2 = { hasReward: 1 };
    axios.put('http://localhost:8080/awardCredit/hasReward/:' + reviewId, body2)
        .then( window.location.href = "http://localhost:3000/viewreviews");
    document.getElementById('creditBtn').style.display='none'
}

<h2>Completed Reviews</h2>
            <div className="writertable">
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Title (Click to View Work)</th>
                            <th>Award Credit(0-1)</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {reviewTaskDisplay.map((val) => (
                            <tr>
                                <td onClick={(e) => viewReview(val.reviewId)}>{val.title}</td>
                                <td><input type="number" id="socialCredit" name="socialCredit" min="0" max="1" 
                                defaultValue="0"/>
                                <button  id="creditBtn" onClick={(e) => 
                                submitCredit(val.reviewer, val.reviewId)}>Submit Credit</button></td>
                            </tr>
                        ))}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
```

Any advice on how I can go about this is appreciated

Comment: It seems you are mixing vanilla JS in with your React.  Are you using class based components or functional components?  The likely solution is to either manage the visibility state of all the buttons in your parent (completed reviews) component or build a button component that manages it's own visibility based on component state using React state (or state helpers if you're using functional components and hooks).

Answer (score 1):

Check this line `<button  id="creditBtn" onClick={(e) => submitCredit(val.reviewer, val.reviewId)}>Submit Credit</button></td>`

You are creating all the buttons with the same id and in the `submitCredit` function, you are applying `display: none` to the same which will remove the buttons that are created by using the same id.

You can do something like this below.

```
<button  id={val.reviewId} onClick={(e) => submitCredit(val.reviewer, val.reviewId)}>Submit Credit</button></td>



// submitCredit
document.getElementById(reviewId).style.display='none'
```

Check [this sanbbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/weathered-brook-0nigue?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)